# How does Internet explorer decide to span a new process for a new browser window?

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer

With the LCIE feature, the Internet Explorer is able to spawn new processes and serve different browser windows with different processes.

How does the Internet Explorer decide to spawn new processes?

I did some tests and observed following behavior:

- With plain web sites, IE usually spawns processes for different
  domains (when hostname or port of the URL is different)
- IE seems also to obey session cookies and some other stuff

The background is, that I have a heavy weighted web application consisting of one main window and different child windows, opened from the main window with JavaScript window.open()
Our child windows use the Acrobat-PDF-viewer to display very large PDF-documents.
This consumes a lot of memory and besides this the PDF Viewer seems to leak memory over time.
Since IE runs as a 32 bit process, we often exceed the memory limited of approx. 1.3 GB.
Since we have lots of memory available, one Idea was, to let IE spawn multiple processes for our child windows.

Is there any possibility to force IE spawning processes for browser windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can force IE to spawn a new process for new browser windows created with this command...

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -noframemerging
```